# MenuBar in the right corner doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, unity, network-manager, vpn

My Menubar doesn't show the icons for "network-manager" and the "indicator-multiload". It worked fine until today. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want that it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using a VPN and recently I had a lot of disconnects so I downloaded this:
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/vpnautoconnect/

It didn't work for me so I removed it, but after a reboot my menu bar looked like this. So I think there is a connection between this two events but I have no idea what exactly.

bash history:

- sudo aptitude update
- sudo aptitude full-upgrade
- ps x
- sudo aptitude purge vpnautoconnect
- sudo aptitude purge vpnautoconnect:i386
- sudo aptitude update
- vim /etc/network/interfaces
- gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
- sudo aptitude install indicator-multiload
- indicator-multiload
- sudo aptitude purge indicator-multiload
- sudo aptitude install indicator-multiload
- indicator-multiload
- sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager nm-applet
- sudo aptitude reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
- indicator-multiload

Comment: Paste the latest lines from your `~/.bash_history` file

Comment: sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
ps-x
ps x
sudo aptitude purge vpnautoconnect
sudo aptitude purge vpnautoconnect:i386
sudo aptitude update
/etc/network/interfaces
vim /etc/network/interfaces
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
sudo aptitude install indicator-multiload
indicator-multiload
sudo aptitude purge indicator-multiload
sudo aptitude install indicator-multiload
indicator-multiload
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
nm-applet
sudo aptitude reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
indicator-multiload

Comment: It is truly impossible to read it from a comment. Edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: where you using 14.04 when it was working, because I think they don't have the systray whitelist anymore

Comment: yes i'm using 14.04 since one month

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this but you can restart or quit the multiload indicator by running the following command in a terminal:

`indicator-multiload &`

Answer (score -1):

The screenshot signifies that the network manager is not running.

To check if network manager is up and running:

```
sudo initctl list | grep "network-manager"
```

To start the network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: Thx for the answer!

Comment: But the network-manager is running: start: Job is already running: network-manager. i'm connected to the internet right now but the icon is missing